# Identifying linear operator with a bilinear symmetric form using Theorem of Schwarz

Tags: derivatives, operator-theory, banach-spaces, dual-spaces, bilinear-form

We study the energy functional $E$ of the form
$$E(v)=\frac{1}{2}a(v,v)+\int_{\Omega}F(x,v).$$
Let $V$ be a real Banach space with norm $||\cdot||_{V}$ and denote by $V^{'}$ the dual space. By $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{V^{'}\times V}$ we denote the duality between the space $V$ and its dual $V^{'}$. 
Let $U\subset V$ be open, and let $E\in C^2(U,\mathbb{R})$. We denote by $\mathcal{M}\in C^1(U,V^{'})$ the first derivate of $E$ and by $\mathcal{L}\in C(U,B(V,V^{'}))$ the second derivate. 
Let $\varphi\in U$ be a stationary point for $E$, i.e. $\mathcal{M}(\varphi)=0$. 
Then, by the Theorem of Schwarz, we may identify the linear operator $\mathcal{L}(\varphi)$ with a bilinear symmetric form on $V\times V$. 

I don't understand how the conclusion arises exactly. The Theorem of Schwarz yields the symmetry of the bilinear form. But why does such a bilinear form exist in the first place, given that the Riesz representation theorem only applies in Hilbert spaces?

Edit: This question is about the proof of Lemma 3.3 in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82204962.pdf

Comment: If you are thinking of "Schwartz Kernel Theorem", then, first, he had a "t" in his name... :) ... but/and, yes, this is a much larger extension of the Riesz-Frechet representation theorem for linear functional, etc., on Hilbert spaces. Can you clarify?

Comment: @paulgarrett it is about the Theorem of Schwarz (without a „t“) :) I added the link to the paper I am referring to

Comment: Every continuous linear operator $T:V\to V'$ induces a bilinear continuous map $\hat T: V\times V\to \mathbb R$, $(x,y)\mapsto T(x)(y)$ (i.e., you evaluate the functional $T(x)$ in $y$ -- although there is no inner product, many authors write this evaluation as $\langle T(x),y\rangle$). -- Completely off-topic: My daughter's name is Hannah and she was born in 2002.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you very much for the explanation! And what a funny coincidence :)